# C++ How to open an input file with another directory?

Tags: c++

My project is being worked in through my school's intranet.
I basically am running the project through Windows Powershell by using ssh login to the intranet.

The data file is located at: `/user/name_of_teacher/data/file_name.dat`.

I have tried:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("/user/name_of_teacher/data/file_name.dat");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If the file is there and you have sufficient rights to access it that should work. But since you are on Windows: Is your current working directory on a different drive than the path you want to open?

Comment: It should be on the same drive. I'm not exactly sure how this intranet (ssh) thing works. He taught us the basic commands such as cd, ls, cat, g++, etc. But we weren't told much about it. Kinda reminds me of Linux. 
I know that when I want to go back to my working directory I do:
cd /user/my_name/cs2560
and when I want to go to his directory
cd /user/teacher_name/data

Comment: "I was told that the data file is located in: `/some/where.dat`" - and did you check whether it's really there? Using the shell? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes I went through the shell and confirmed that the file was there.

Comment: @Amai: So you should have just written that's where the file is. I have edited your message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write in this file:

```
ofstream file("C:/user/name_of_teacher/data/file_name.dat");
file << text;
```

If you want to read in this file:

```
ifstream file("C:/user/name_of_teacher/data/file_name.dat");
file >> text;
```

Remember to write:
`using namespace std;`
at the start of the file cpp but after the libraries.

The principle error was that you had to use the absolute location:
C:\Users ecc.

Comment: The OP's system might be a Unix one, so without `C:`

Comment: so he has to use home/ or root/

Comment: No, that Unix system could have some large disk mounted on `/user/` (with an `e`). Such non-standard things can happen.

Comment: I'm personally using windows, but it seems that the commands through intranet is Linux commands.
Also, when I change it to what you mentioned, it fails to open the file (I have an error message in place).

Comment: It could be some permission issues. See for example the many failure reasons for the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) *system call* on Linux

Comment: `using namespace std` is a very bad practice.